# Ajax Function working localhost in mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post an object into json server but I got the 500 internal server error. In this code is working fine in localHost but live not working, any this wrong in my code

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/Booking/CheckAvailability',
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  data: { 
    LocationID: locationID, 
    VenueID: venueID, 
    FacilityID: facilityID, 
    BookedFromDate: bookedFromDate, 
    BookedToDate: bookedToDate, 
    FromTime: fromtime, 
    ToTime: Ttime 
  },
  traditional: true,
  success: function (data) {
    if (data.success) {
      $("#VenueBooking").show();
    }
    if (data.False) {
      alert("Aleardy Booked");
    }
  },
  error: function (ex) {
    alert('Failed to retrieve Sub Categories : ' + ex);
  }
});
```

The data Value not passed to controller any thing wrong in my code?

COntroller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CheckAvailability(int locationID, int venueID, int facilityID, string bookedFromDate, string bookedToDate, string fromTime, string toTime)
        {

            try
            {
                Get_Location();
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    locationInformation check = new locationInformation();
                    bool suc = check.CheckAvailability(bookedFromDate, bookedToDate, fromTime, toTime);
                    if (suc == false)
                    {
                        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Checked successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                    else if (suc == true)
                    {
                        return Json(new { False = true, message = "Checked successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                }
                return View();
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us the controller  action?

Comment: I would bet there is a configuration error. 500 can be anything horrible happened. You need to look at your logs from the service and check you configurations.

Comment: @apomene Updated code

Comment: Maybe the variable name has a mismatch from ajax and C# method parameter. EX: LocationID maybe given as LocationId in C#. Better you can add all the data in a single object like (var a={b:b, c:c}) and then pass it like data: {a:a} and use the same "a" as param in C# method.

Comment: Gotta say, `False = true` forced my brain to reboot ...

Comment: Also use json.stringify

Comment: not sure how you say its working on local but not on the server, as per the code given it should not work in local too... the parameters are case sensitive.. you should use Pascal Case in your server-side code

Comment: @Chidambaram yes you are correct i

Comment: `return Json(new { False = true`...surely it should be `success = false` to indicate failure instead of `False = true`. Then it's consistent with the structure returned when it's sucessful

Comment: 500 response means, your code is crashing. log the exception in your `catch` block and that will give you some idea why it is crashing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in arguments naming. On client side you define args to be pascal case wheres as in your action they are lowercase. Example for 1st arg on client should be:

```
locationID: locationID,
...
```

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` is not case sensitive!